# ASP.NET MVC deployment routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've built a WebDeploy package of my ASP.NET MVC 4 website in Visual Studio 2012.

When I run the deployer on my server, it successfully deploys the website to a subdir on my server called `/myapp`

However, when I navigate to `localhost/myapp` in a browser, I get a 404. It appears IIS is looking for a physical path (one-to-one). How can I config IIS, or setup a rewrite rule, so that `/myapp` functions within itself?

For example, links and redirects that the website has are pointing to `localhost/static/style.css`, when they *should* be pointing to `localhost/myapp/static/style.css`

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS 7. I think adding the ~ mark may work. Going to try right now. Strange this doesn't work right out of the box though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tilde in your paths to tell ASP.NET to follow the path from the application root:

```
~/static/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an Application in IIS called `myapp`? It should have the path pointing to where you deployed the files for the website - in your case: `/myapp`